# Gem install takes forever

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am building and installing a local gem. Also with verbose gem install just sits there and waits for a long long time. No output.

When there is output it finishes in seconds.

One would expect install of local gem to go quickly but evidently it is doing something, maybe on the network, although the gem is local, which takes forever.

Any ideas on how this can fixed?

Comment: Would you mind to show us a `Gemfile`?

Comment: I can do that but I think I already found the problem. I have to set/unset proxy settings often and it seems that the rubygems keeps using the proxy server even when I am not using it for example on home network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can do that but I think I already found the problem.

I have to set/unset proxy settings often and it seems that the rubygems keeps using the proxy server even when I am not using it for example on home network.

```
unset http_proxy
```

fixes the problem as a consequence. I didn't expect network would be used as the gem is local and all dependencies are satisfied. As it turns out Rubygems tries to use the network. There is no error message btw. No timeout error or anything. The gem installs without error messages. It just takes a very long time and gives no clue that anything is wrong.

Comment: I also had to add the `--local` option to my `gem install` invocation. Otherwise thanks for pointing me in the right direction (network stall).